# Is a card with devoid colorless on the stack?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

A card with *devoid* is colorless. But is it still colorless when it's a spell? I mean: when is it in the stack, that is, when it is not yet a permanent, and when it has not yet been resolved?

As an example, I can take a card called [Unnatural Aggression](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUnnatural%20Aggression%5d) (mana cost 2G,so that at first glance it may seem that the spell is green). Is it possible to choose as one of this spell's targets a creature that has "protection from colored spells" among its abilities?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> 702.113a Devoid is a characteristic-defining ability. “Devoid” means “This object is colorless.” This ability functions everywhere, even outside the game. See rule 604.3.

'Everywhere' includes the stack, so a creature with protection from green can still be targeted by Unnatural Aggression.

Comment: Hi Glorfinder, and thanks. I started a "bounty" in order to get you a well-deserved prize from me for the many good answers received from you. But, still knowing too little about the options, I failed to adequately communicate my intention, and Murgatroid did not find my proposal interesting, canceling the "bounty". I hope to be able to repeat the operation better, maybe another time, and for better questions.

Comment: No problem, and remember you need the reputation more than I do :)

Comment: I do not care much about reputation...